# Is path starting from / but containing .. still absolute?

Tags: php, linux, path

There is an advice about php, that using an *absolute* file path in `include/require` statements is preferable than *relative* one. Because in that case no need to normalizing a relative file path which can be expensive. So my question is: if i need to *include* script from one level directory above like `__DIR__ . '/../script.php'`. Is it still absolute ? I mean `__DIR__` will be replaced at runtime with something like */var/www/site/subdir* but this 2 dots in path still exists and when including file php needs to normalize file's path into */var/www/site/script.php* or it will remains `/var/www/site/subdir/../script.php` and better to replace it with someting like `realpath('__DIR__ . '/../script.php')` ?

Comment: it's just for illustration, case may be `__DIR__ . '/../script.php'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you mention in your question is absolute although you will probably want to use a function to retrieve it instead of hardcoding.

Example:

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/script.php' );
```

Or:

```
// define path to application root somewhere (modify if file defining root isn't in the root folder)
define( 'APP_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) );

require_once( APP_ROOT . '/some-dir/xyz/script.php' );
```